# Parsing bash command input in C

Tags: c, string, bash, parsing

I'm writing a simple shell in C. Part of this shell uses bash commands that need to be split up into an array of characters, so that I can properly execute the commands. As a simple proof of concept, I wanted to make a C program that would check to see if its a word, or a special character (`|`, `&`, `>`, and `<`).

Here is an example of how it should look:

```
input a command: cat hello.txt |wc -l
---output---
cat
hello.txt
|
wc
-l
```

So far, I've gotten every case to work, for example except for one, and that is when I do a special character like in `|wc l` where a letter is **after** the special character. Here is what my current output looks like:

```
input a command: cat hello.txt |wc -l
---output---
cat
hello.txt
|wc
-l
```

Below is my code, I've tried adding special cases, removing cases, and nothing seems to work correctly. How should I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALPHABET 1000
#define LESS_THAN 60
#define GREATER_THAN 62
#define AMPERSAND 38
#define PIPE 124
#define WHITESPACE 32
#define NEWLINE 10
#define MYCOPOUT 9999

#define CAPITALS(i) ((i >= 65) && (i <= 90))
#define LOWERS(i) ((i >= 97) && (i <= 122))
#define BACKSLASH(i) i == 47

int classify(int i)
{
    if (CAPITALS(i) || LOWERS(i) || BACKSLASH(i))
        return ALPHABET;
    return i;
}

char isSpecial(int i)
{
    return (i == LESS_THAN) ||(i == GREATER_THAN) || (i == AMPERSAND) || (i == PIPE);
}

char isWhiteSpace(int i)
{
    return (i == WHITESPACE) || (i == NEWLINE);
}

void PRINT_N_NEW(int c, int last)
{
    if (isWhiteSpace(last)) {
        printf("%c",c);
    } else if(isSpecial(last)) {
        printf("\n%c\n",c);
    } else {
        printf("%c\n", c);
    }
    last = c;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int i;
    int last = MYCOPOUT;
    while ( (i = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch(classify(i)){
            case ALPHABET:
                printf("%c",i);
                last = i;
                break;
            case LESS_THAN:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case GREATER_THAN:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case AMPERSAND:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case PIPE:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case WHITESPACE:
                printf("\n");
                last = i;
                break;
            case NEWLINE:
                printf("\n");
                last = i;
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c",i);
                last = i;
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `ctype.h` `isspace()` instead of `isWhiteSpace(int i)`. And this, `#define AMPERSAND 38` is not needed you just nee `#define AMPERSAND '&'`

Comment: Don't name functions with all uppercase. By convention, that's used for macros.

Comment: If you want to replicate *bash* behavior, better look at *bash* code... But you probably want just something resembling Unix shells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting `last` every time through the loop, only in certain cases of the `switch`. You should also use `PRINT_N_NEW` when printing ordinary characters, so that it will test the last character and put a newline before it. Finally, if the character you're printing is a special character, you need to print a newline before it.

There's no point in doing `last = c` at the end of `PRINT_N_NEW`. That doesn't set the variable in the caller, it just sets the local copy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALPHABET 1000
#define LESS_THAN 60
#define GREATER_THAN 62
#define AMPERSAND 38
#define PIPE 124
#define WHITESPACE 32
#define NEWLINE 10
#define MYCOPOUT 9999

#define CAPITALS(i) ((i >= 65) && (i <= 90))
#define LOWERS(i) ((i >= 97) && (i <= 122))
#define BACKSLASH(i) i == 47

int classify(int i)
{
    if (CAPITALS(i) || LOWERS(i) || BACKSLASH(i))
        return ALPHABET;
    return i;
}

char isSpecial(int i)
{
    return (i == LESS_THAN) ||(i == GREATER_THAN) || (i == AMPERSAND) || (i == PIPE);
}

char isWhiteSpace(int i)
{
    return (i == WHITESPACE) || (i == NEWLINE);
}

void PRINT_N_NEW(int c, int last)
{
    if (isWhiteSpace(last)) {
        printf("%c",c);
    } else if(isSpecial(last) || isSpecial(c)) {
        printf("\n%c",c);
    } else {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int i;
    int last = MYCOPOUT;
    while ( (i = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch(classify(i)){
            case ALPHABET:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i, last);
                break;
            case LESS_THAN:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case GREATER_THAN:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case AMPERSAND:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case PIPE:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i,last);
                break;
            case WHITESPACE:
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case NEWLINE:
                printf("\n");
                break;
            default:
                PRINT_N_NEW(i, last);
                break;
        }
        last = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you should use strtok?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

try to separate substrings with " " symbol, it might be useful

To solve the problem, you could check if the first char of the token is a symbol

if ( token[0] == "|" )
  aux_str = token+1;

It could be like:

```
enter code here
#define (CMD_SEPARATORS) ("|<>&")


int function interpretCMD(char *s){
    char **args = malloc (sizeof(char*) * MAX_ARGS);


    cmd = strtok (s, " ");

    args = strtok(s);
    while (cmd != NULL){
        args[i] = strtok(s);
    }
/*
    at this point you must have cmd the cmd
    and in args[i] the i argument
*/
}

int function parseCMD(char *s){
    cmd = strtok(s, CMD_SEPARATORS);
    while (cmd!= NULL){
        interpretCMD(token);
        cmd = strtok(s);
    }
}

main blablah

while ( (line = getline()) != EOF){
    parseCMD(line);


}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with where he prints newlines while scanning?

Comment: well, the strtok function allows you to get every word in the line readed from input. So you'll be able to interpret as bash like: cmd = first_token, every next token are arguments unless token[0] its in ("|",";","&",">", "<") -> manage that options with a switch to redirect input or launch two commands at time, etc.

Comment: What if he writes `cat foo|wc -l`. Checking just `token[0]` won't find that.

Comment: uuuhmm you're right, well, strtok allow to make the separation on one or more symbols... may be.... strtok (line, " |;&><"); i'm thinking on that please wait

Comment: uhum what if you make a function like
`
for (i=0; i<strlen(token);i++)
if (isSymbol(token[i])) then blablah()`

Comment: or simplified: first of all get all command tried to be executed, get commands as tokens based on cmd separator symbols. After that, execute recursively the same function to interpret every cmd

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine,

```
if (isWhiteSpace(last)) {
    printf("%c\n",c);
```

Place the new line in this print statement. Or else place the new line after when pipe is came.

Comment: This works somewhat.. however for some reason, if I do `echo hello| world` it now results in `echo`, `hello|`, `world` (each comma is a new line)